# Pin a shortcut of a vbs script to the taskbar (W2008 Server)

Tags: windows, vbscript

I have a VBS that that make some actions and then call a program :
"C:\Program Files (x86)\myprogram.exe"

I have created a shortcut to the vbs file and put the icon of myprogram.exe
The users think they launch myprogram.exe but they launch the script. (ie some actions and then launch the program).

Now, users want to pin the shorcut to the taskbar. When we pin the shortcut to the taskbar, 
it don't launch the script, it laucnch "Settings of Windows script Host".

It looks like this : 
http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1107337-how-can-i-pin-a-vbs-file-to-the-windows-8-taskbar/

Can someone have a solution to do that without using a .bat file that launch the script.
Thanks.

I have found this solution, change the target in  shortcut : 
"C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\myscript.vbs"
The problem is that cscript open during 2ms one dosbox.

Do you know a way to avoid the dosbox ?

Regards

Comment: Find it ! After 3 hours, the solution is to call myprogram.exe with wscript.exe.

Comment: You could add this as an answer, and accept it if that´s what helped. Even though it might look silly to answer your own question, it helps a) other users to find the answer more easily, and b) washes the question away from the list of unanswered questions (which already is full of similar cases, or low-quality questions).

Comment: Oh, and you probably mean the solution is to call the VBS script (which in turn calls myprogram.exe) with wscript.exe. Not to call myprogram.exe with wscript.exe, right?

Answer (score 9):

I confirm the author's solution in Windows 10. Using `wscript "C:\path\to\foo.vbs"` as a shortcut target I can pin my VBS's to the taskbar, and they won't even open a console when running !

Comment: great, it works in windows11 too